# Nested dictionaries from file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm trying to create a nested dictionary but I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic.

So say I have input coming in from a csv:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
1,4,5
```

Now'd like to create a dictionary as follows:

```
d ={1:{2:3,4:5}, 2:{3:4}}
```

Such that for the first being some ID column that we create keys in the sub dictionary corresponding to second value.

The way I tried it was to go:

```
d[row[0]] = {row[1]:row[2]}
```

But that overwrites the first instead of appending/pushing to it, how would I go about this problem? I can't seem to wrap my mind around what keys to use.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `dict` overwrites a builtin function. Pick a different name for your dictionary. `dict[row[0]] = ...` just overwrites the existing object with a new one. If it exists, add a new property on it.

Comment: Should've been more clear, I just wrote that example. I'll change the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cause `dict[row[0]] =` is `dict[1] =` what overwrites previous `dict[1]` value 
You should use :

```
dict.setdefault(row[0],{})[row[1]] = row[2]
```

remember there must be no duplicates for row[1] then

or

```
dict.setdefault(row[0],{}).update({row[1]:row[2]})
```

Comment: I didn't know about set default that was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: oh yes and you should not call the valiable dict cause it overwrites the dict type

Answer (score 0):

```
if dict[row[0]] == None:
    dict[row[0]] = {row[1]:row[2]}
else:
    dict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
```

Comment: No need for `== None` (switch the statements in the blocks), and it's best practice to use `is None` if you do need to compare against None. Correct answer though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use defaultdict, which is similaire to the built-in dictionaries, but will create dictionaries with a default values, in your case a default value will be a dictionary

```
from collections import  defaultdict
res = defaultdict(dict)
```

with this code we are creating a defaultdict, with it's values default value being of type dict, so next we would do

```
for row in l:
    res[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
```